# Lotus nots script , assign to a field , parametric , using function

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I need to create a function and to pass a variable which represent a field on a document.
At the and in the same function I try to update the field , but is not work.
Actually , I need to remove a member from a list.
Table AllStringTable has the correct members but line
"varFieldToRemoveMembers = AllStringTable" does not update field.
What is missing ? Thanks to advice me.

```
Function funcRemoveMembersFromAField (varFieldToRemoveMembers As Variant , varFieldToRemoveMembersSTR As String , varMemberToRemove As Variant) 

Dim TableIndex As Integer

Forall memebers  In varFieldToRemoveMembers
    If memebers <> "" Then
        If varMemberToRemove = memebers Then
            ' do nothing
        Else
            Redim Preserve AllStringTable(TableIndex) As String 
            AllStringTable(TableIndex)  = memebers
            TableIndex =   TableIndex + 1
        End If  
    End If
End Forall

Set ReadersItem=note.GetFirstItem(varFieldToRemoveMembersSTR) 
If Not ReadersItem Is Nothing   Then
    varFieldToRemoveMembers = AllStringTable   
    Call note.Save(True,False)      
End If  

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually modifing the field (the ReadersItem). You are only changing your temporary variables.

Try something like this:

```
Set ReadersItem=note.GetFirstItem(varFieldToRemoveMembersSTR) 
If Not ReadersItem Is Nothing Then
    Call note.replaceItemValue(varFieldToRemoveMembersSTR, AllStringTable)   
    Call note.Save(True,False)      
End If
```

Comment: Even better... There's no need to use GetFirstItem That line can be removed. Then change the second line to If Not note.hasItem(varFieldToRemoveMembersSTR).  Also, to make sure that the item remains a ReaderNames, I would call note.ComputeWithForm(true). I honestly don't know if this is required, but it used to be way back when, otherwise you could end up with an ordinary text item. I still do it as a matter of habit.

Comment: note.ReplaceItemValue(.., ..).Readers= True ‘ why ComputeWithForm?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that IsReaders is a settable property, that's why! I learned this stuff back in R4, and I think ComputeWithForm was the only way back then. But perhaps it's been settable all along.

Comment: I can't remember when I actually adopted the .Readers property this way (also avoiding the Call :-)). We used to have CwF-calls all over the place too, until I discovered that the ReplaceItemValue method returns the NotesItem.